Add a [tag:non-ai]?
We have artificial-intelligence. While AI was a niche feature some years ago and one had to search for AI products actively, AI now becomes part of more and more products. Even Paint and Notepad seem to get AI features.
For me, offline is a feature, because I don't want my data to be sent to servers and I don't have Internet every day.
Likewise, for some functionality, I want a real algorithm, made by a human, who put thought into it. Honestly, I don't want a text editor send my data to a server with every keypress, just to get a guess of what I might type. Even an offline AI may be a hindrance.
All in all, I think non-ai might become a feature in the future. Can we prepare for that? I would definitely use it. First, I need a Notepad without AI, then Paint without AI ;-)

"Even an offline AI may be a hindrance." What's the issue?

@FranckDernoncourt: "I want a real algorithm, made by a human, who put thought into it." - and not just some statistical likeliness. E.g. I want a calculator that produces mathematically correct results, and not just statistically correct results. Therefore I want a non-AI calculator, even offline.

Thanks, I see. Typically AI is used when human-made algos aka rule-based systems (aka the calculator) don't work well, eg speech recognition. But yes there are some cases where rule-based systems are decent enough to be useful, e.g. spell checking.
